# C# UWP MedieElement MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder

Tags: c#, xaml, mediaelement, uwp, commandbar

Trying to figure out how `MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder` works when attaching a custom `MediaTransportControl` to a `MediaElement` in `C# UWP` and having a little trouble.

I assumed that if say, I had 4 buttons in my custom `MediaTransportControl` and I resized the app so that only 3 fit, the last (`MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder="4"`) button would 'drop out' to some overflow menu (`CommandBar.SecondaryCommands`?) - but I'm not seeing this is the case.

Anyone have any idea how to achieve this? Or any samples on hand to guide me?

Thanks.

Comment: So it seems according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/mt187271, I need to add an `AppBarButton` to `CommandBar.SecondaryCommands` with a matching name to get this to work -- but when I compile I get an `Element name 'PlaybackRateButton' is already used in this scope`.

Comment: I think you need to remove it from primary command with Childeren.Remove(yourbutton), and add it to secondary commands.